# Can the integral from -2 to 1 of |x|d|x| be computed?

Tags: integration

The question of the computation of
$$\int_{-2}^1|x|d|x|$$
came up on quora, and I tried my best to answer it as the mathematical layman I am here: [https://www.quora.com/How-can-we-integrate-int-limits-1-_-2-left-x-right-d-left-x-right/answer/Kenny-Duran-1?**snids**=1376205505&**nsrc**=1&**filter**=all](https://www.quora.com/How-can-we-integrate-int-limits-1-_-2-left-x-right-d-left-x-right/answer/Kenny-Duran-1?__snids__=1376205505&__nsrc__=1&__filter__=all)

Later on, a fellow in the same thread pointed out that the limits of integration have to be changed when there are differential substitutions. Our angles can be found here:
[https://www.quora.com/How-can-we-integrate-int-limits-1-_-2-left-x-right-d-left-x-right/answer/Martin-Scholtz-2/comment/13094879?**snids**=1366723553&**nsrc**=1&**filter**=all#comment13131886](https://www.quora.com/How-can-we-integrate-int-limits-1-_-2-left-x-right-d-left-x-right/answer/Martin-Scholtz-2/comment/13094879?__snids__=1366723553&__nsrc__=1&__filter__=all#comment13131886)

While he does make a compelling argument, when he brings up that the change in differential requires a change in the limits of integration and that |x| has no inverse to refer to for the limits of integration, I am again skeptical. If I were to continue, which I can't because of time and insufficient mathematical maturity, I would argue that |x| does have an inverse in the form of a piecewise, which is what I referred to in my original post, albeit in bad notation.

Since I am hardly formal enough to communicate this well and rigorously, I'd like to know whether the experts here think that the function is integrable or not.

Comment: |x| cannot be less than zero.  So a bound of -2 makes no sense.  There is no Riemann sum which can be constructed to have this make sense.

Comment: That's not how Riemann-Stieljes integrals work, @Paul By your reasoning, there is no meaning to $\int_{-1}^1 f(x)\,d(x^2)$, but there is - it is $\int_{-1}^1 2xf(x)\,dx$.

Comment: Certainly it makes sense! This is just a Stieltjes integral. Avoinding technicalities by assuming that $f$ and $\gamma$ are continuous (and $\gamma$ has bounded variation), a Riemann-Stieltjes sum for $\int_a^b f\,d\gamma$ is just $\sum_{j=1}^nf(t_j)(\gamma(x_j)-\gamma(x_{j-1})$, where $a=x_0<\dots<x_n=b$ and $t_j\in[x_{j-1},x_j]$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, that integral makes no sense either.  The change of variables formula is not a definition; it is a theorem with conditions that are not met here.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, so what is $\gamma(-2)$ in this case?

Comment: @Paul I think you need to look up Riemann-Stieljes integrals. You are wrong. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral

Comment: $\gamma(-2)=2$. @Paul

Comment: The absolute value of $-2$ is $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to calculate $\int_a^b f(x)\, d g(x)$ for the case where $g$ is continuous and piecewise continuously differentiable is as $\int_a^b f(x) g'(x) \, dx$, so in this case you get $\int_{-2}^0 (-x)(-1) \, dx + \int_0^1 x\, dx$, and from here on it should be easy...

Comment: g meets none of the conditions you give here.